# Push notifications from Adobe Business Catalyst

Tags: business-catalyst

I would like to receive push notifications to an external application from Business Catalyst when a customer submits a case.  I am hoping that the `Enter URL of your application to notify for new Customer Inquiries` in `Site Settings > API Integration` is what I can use for this, but I haven't as yet discovered any documentation.

In the absence of documentation, I thought I'd set the URL to a generic HTTP POST request listener, create a case, and inspect the response.

However, upon creating a case, the listener doesn't appear to receive anything.  So either 'Customer Inquiries' != 'Case', or there is some magic glue which is not in place to allow a Case to be submitted to the URL.

Can anyone shed any light on this?  A link to some documentation, or a clarification as to what a 'Customer Inquiry' is, or the recipe for the magic glue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Customer Inquiry notification is definitely triggered by a submission to the default Contact Form, and should work for any other 'Web Form'.

There is usually a delay of roughly ten minutes before the notification is sent.

The Inquiry notification is a `POST` request, of `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and will have a body like:

```
ObjectID=2087865&ObjectType=2001
```

For inquiry forms, `ObjectID` will be the Case ID.

---

I don't think this (or the `ObjectType` codes) are officially documented anywhere.

Comment: Robert - you are 100% right.  I've double checked the POST checker I was using [RequestBin](http://requestb.in/) which keeps POSTs received for 48 hours, and sure enough - there it was.  Thank you - without your assurance, I'd never have checked back there.